# How to generate a sine wave with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-recording

I would like to generate an audio file with a sine (sinusoid) wave with FFmpeg. I know there is a `sine` filter but that's as far as it goes.

I tried:

```
fmpeg -filter "sine=48:1:5" -c:a pcms16le test
```

to create 5 seconds of audio at 48kHz in PCM S16LE format, but I got the following error message:

> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

and the `test` file is empty.

Comment: You can also play a sine without creating a file with `ffplay`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109038/linux-sinus-audio-generator/57610684#57610684

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To generate a 1000 Hz signal for 5 seconds duration use this:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" test.wav
```

You can add `-c:a pcm_s16le`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" -c:a pcm_s16le test.wav
```

To also set the sampling rate to 48 KHz:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:sample_rate=48000:duration=5" -c:a pcm_s16le test.wav
```

Comment: You can also set the amplitude by adding for example: `-af "volume=-18dB"` (for -18dBFS).

Answer (score 13):

Apologies for necro-ing this, but in the event that someone from the future comes looking for this, if you wanted to do this in stereo, you would do the following:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" -ac 2 output.wav
```

You could also use `-filter_complex` with `amerge`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" -filter_complex "[0:a][0:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.wav
```