# FFmpeg: make stereo from two wavs and convert to opus

Tags: ffmpeg

I need make stereo from two wavs and convert result stereo to opus.
I do :

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -i out.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]"  stereo.wav  &&  ffmpeg -i stereo.wav   -c:a libopus -ac 1 -ar 16000  -b:a 8k -vbr  constrained  record.opus
```

But record.opus doesn't look stereo.

If I execute two commands separately result file is stereo.

Comment: All you need to do is get rid of `-ac 1` from the 2nd command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options, either `join` or `amerge`, but the one for `join` in the documentation appears not to work (as you've found). Here is an example for two working command lines:

1. Create two audio test files. I've [used `sox`](https://www.audiosciencereview.com/forum/index.php?threads/howto-sox-audio-tool-as-a-signal-generator.4242/) but you can apparently [use `ffmpeg`](https://superuser.com/a/724462/332907)

   ```
   # 3 seconds each of a 1kHz and 1.5kHz tone
   sox -V -r 48000 -n -b 16 -c 2 left.wav synth 3 sin 1000 vol -10dB
   sox -V -r 48000 -n -b 16 -c 2 right.wav synth 3 sin 1500 vol -10dB
   ```
2. Combine [as stereo](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)

   You can use [`join`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join), where I've found that, contrary to the documentation, the `map=…` part is required:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i left.wav -i right.wav -filter_complex 'join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR' stereo.opus
   ```

   And you can use [`amerge`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

   ```
   ffmpeg -i left.wav -i right.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" stereo.opus
   ```